# What is the proper way to finalize a method that is async*

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method that tries to login into a service. If the login has successful it query the bonus and clientName. Otherwise it shoulds send a message and have quit the method.

So if it verifies the session is not logged, I send a message and uses return to quit method. I wonder if this is the correct way to do that, it seems a little weird.  Is there a better way to finalize this kind of method?

```
@override
  Stream<GetUserInfoState> mapEventToState(
    GetUserInfoEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetUserInfoEventImpl) {
      yield ConnectingState();
      var session = event.session;

      await for (final message in session.login()){
        yield new MessageState(message);
      }

      if (!await session.isLogged) {
        yield new MessageState('Could not connect');
        return;
      }

      var bonus = await session.bonusPoints;
      var clientName = await session.clientName;

      yield new SuccessfulState(clientName, bonus, getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What about throwing an exception?

Comment: I would like to avoid having to handle an exception. The clientName and bonus are secondary information, that will be shown only it the users provide credentials. But it's a way, too.

Comment: I also use *return* to end my method, but only If there is more branches and subbranches. In your example, use *else* instead of *return* make more intuitive to me.

Comment: Apologies for prev comments, I think It's good to use *return* in this case, but you could be more better to extract to a new function according to different child of *GetUserInfoEvent*.